# How do I can use "grep" on dynamically changing text?

Tags: python, bash, awk, grep, cut

so i've been wondering how can i get the variable x and y while using awk?

```
wall@bot:~$ geoiplookup 98.90.005.015
GeoIP Country Edition: USA, Alaska
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: UK, 12, Oakland, Wealth, 2155, XX.XXXX, YY.YYYY, 0, 0
GeoIP ASNum Edition: BS822828 McDonalds, America
```

Im appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Welcome to SO, what is the condition to get them?

Comment: I want do a small change to the 'MapSCII' so you can feed it IP's my only problem is the awk part

Comment: But your requirement is not clear? Which part of command's output you need in your output by using awk? Kindly elaborate more.

Comment: I need the Geolocation x = longitude, y = latitude

Comment: ok, but how do I let my program know that go to this line and do some stuff? Could you please give me information like, I should look for 2nd line and for last field or second field etc etc.

Comment: Yes its located in the 2 second line but than I look at this line I see that everything is seperated by a comma and couldnt awk not just count the fields up until it reaches the geo part ?

Comment: It's like pulling teeth. OK you've told us now that `its located in the 2 second line`, next step is to tell us WHERE on the second line. Is it always the same number of fields from the start of the line? From the end? Does it follow some pattern that we could mach with a regexp? Anything else we need to know to find it? What should the output look like - multiple values on 1 line, multiple lines, something else? Are there always exactly 3 lines of output? Are there multiple records in the input or just 1? etc., etc...

Comment: Looking at the labels... you want to do this with `python`? Or `awk`? Or `grep`? Or `cut`? What have you tried so far and what specifically you'd like to improve on or need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s=$(geoiplookup 98.90.005.015 |awk -F', ' 'NR==2 {print $7,$8}')

x=$(echo $s |awk '{print $1}')
y=$(echo $s |awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: To make this slightly more readable or self-documenting, I'd probably change the subshell from the first line to be `geoiplookup [ip addr] | grep "GeoIP City Edition"`

Comment: Whatever it is the OP is trying to do, multiple calls to awk with pipes, subshells, and unquoted variables is not the right way to do it. Also, @AneeshDurg, wrt your comment you never need grep when you're using awk since `cmd | grep foo | awk 'bar'` = `cmd | awk '/foo/{bar}'`